# How to develop offline apps in microsoft without it getting its refresh_token expire after 90 days

Tags: php, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, outlook-restapi

Just visited the link "http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime/" for reference and found out that the `refresh_token` received from microsoft **OAuth2.0 will only work for 90 days** of exhaustive usage and after that we need to let the users authenticate the microsoft app once again

How are we supposed to develop microsoft apps with `offline_access` scope if the `refresh_token` is only gonna work for the next 90 days of time?

The user might not visit the webapp again and he might need the microsoft app to do its job in the background and serve the purpose...

Should we notify the users through some method(email, sms, ivr phone call) to re-authenticate the microsoft app? That sounds tedious for the developer and uncomfortable for the user...

Is there any overriding mechanism to solve this dilemma? please share any ideas or workarounds so my soul may REST in peace...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently not a mechanism to retrieve the refresh token within Mobile Services. This is something about to be enabled for App Service Mobile Apps, but as of right now it is not available through the basic LoginAsync(“aad”) flow. This article talks about [How to Best handle AAD access tokens in native mobile apps](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/how-to-best-handle-aad-access-tokens-in-native-mobile-apps/) and would do help.

If you need a better refresh support, and if you are using the .NET backend, then you can certainly use [ADAL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-adal-sso-authentication/). It has an overload for LoginAsync which additionally accepts the access token (as part of a JSON object, under the key “access_token”). This allows the client to handle the refresh action.

Comment: The blog [How to Best handle AAD access tokens in native mobile apps](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/how-to-best-handle-aad-access-tokens-in-native-mobile-apps/) did not solve the 90 days `refresh_token` expiry. in case of mobile apps its okay to show the login screen to users to login again(since they have their mobile phones with them and they won't find it uncomfortable)... but in case of web apps services, we have no clear way to do this as the users might register to a service once and they'll hope that service continues to run even when they're not logged in to the service

Answer (score 0):

We can find the quote on [Best Practices for OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645536.aspx)

> Refresh tokens do not have specified lifetimes. Typically, the lifetimes of refresh tokens are relatively long. However, in some cases, refresh tokens expire, are revoked, or lack sufficient privileges for the desired action. The client application needs to expect and handle errors returned by the token issuance endpoint correctly. When you receive a response with a refresh token error, discard the current refresh token and request a new authorization code or access token. In particular, when using a refresh token in the Authorization Code Grant flow, if you receive a response with the interaction_required or invalid_grant error codes, discard the refresh token and request a new authorization code.

Which means, when the `refresh_token` expire, you will get an error if you use this token to apply for a new `access_token`.

So you can write the error handler in your code script, when using a refresh token in the Authorization Code Grant flow, if you receive a response with the `interaction_required` or `invalid_grant` error codes, you need to discard the refresh token and request a new authorization code.

Comment: that's what I'm worried about. If I request for a new authorization code, the user must login and authenticate the APP once again... until then the time crucial process and services might cease to work... so how would I be able to force the users to login and authenticate the microsoft app in web as soon as the refresh token is used exhaustively after 90 days???

Comment: Actually, the workflow should be like this. Each time, your user authenticate the ms app, you can save the refresh_token. Then when your user request ms app service, you use the `refresh_token` for a new `access_token`. If the user do not have a `refresh_token` or you get an error during requesting the `access_token` by `refresh_token`, you can force to run the authorization code in the  Authorization Code Grant flow

Comment: Yes... when I run the Authorization grant flow, the user's presence is needed... My need is to let the user authenticate the app once and (I'll store the `refresh_token` obviously and fetch the `access_token` after its expiry and fetch and save `refresh_token` within 14 days that is also obvious) my microsoft app (with `offline_access` scope) will do its work in the server in a cron job... So I'm finding ways to bypass the 90 days `refresh_token` expiry issue... if `refresh_token` expires after 90 days, I'll be in a loss as to make the user login the web app, re-authenticate the ms app

Comment: I feel uncomfortable involving the user once after 90 days to re-authenticate the microsoft app... is there any special scope that we can use to make the `refresh_token`'s expiry date to infinite? If user logs into the security settings and removes the app permission, I totally understand... but if he doesn't, then we should not bother the users to login and re-authenticate... its a total waste of time and **"time critical process"** will suffer much...

Comment: The link you've referred, doesn't mention the lifetime of `refresh_token` but a few other blogs [Azure AD Token Lifetime](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime/) and the link in the answer by @Steven clearly specifies that there is an expiration time for how long we can request and use the `refresh_token`. They've referred to the azure cloud instance "Azure AD" resource... but I'm worried that this'll also apply for the microsoft app registered in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

Comment: Dose you want your user only needs to authenticate once, and use ms app service forever? If so, I am afraid you cannot implement this requirement. Both authentication for AAD or ms app is followed in Auth0 2 grant, and follow its rule. And there is no articles point that we can set `refresh_token` expire time on its official guide at https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/  or https://auth0.com/docs/refresh-token